# Why hover over image pin it button won't appear

Tags: javascript, html, pinterest

I've added the appropriate js link from pinterest in the appropriate place on my website, and checked all the known errors and still can't seem to get the pin it button to appear on the images of my site.

Thanks for any help. Here is the page live on my personal website:

http://lancebeaudry.com/lindsay/

Comment: [This thing?](http://i.imgur.com/07hJXeY.png)

Comment: When i hover over the image i can see it on the right side of the screen. Yet i cannot click it, because once i leave the "image" area it dissapears. Its not appearing on the right place, maybe you should check the CSS or the code where does it show up? As seen now, its probably outside of image boundary, or you have some margins set.

Comment: Try adding an image outside of the slider, it's most likely that the slider is causing a conflict somehow.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It's definitely an issue caused by the slider. I didn't think of that. Now I'll have to figure out how I'm going to solve that issue. Any help is appreciate, thanks!

Comment: @carlodurso do you happen to know how I could fix the slider issue? - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed:

```
<div>
  <img src="images/img1.jpg" class="slider-img">
</div>
<!----far away---->
<a class="..." title="Pin it!" data-pin-log="button_pinit_floating" data-pin-href="//www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?..." style="top: 110px; left: 1895px; z-index: 8675309; display: block;"></a>
```

Change that to:

```
<div>
  <a class="..." title="Pin it!" data-pin-log="button_pinit_floating" data-pin-href="//www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?..." style="top: 110px; left: 1585px; z-index: 8675309; display: block;"></a>
  <img src="images/img1.jpg" class="slider-img">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixing the slider can be kind of complicated, but I tell you about the process I'd follow.

Go to https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/blob/master/slick/slick.js and download it locally.

The error is most probably related to the swiping effect, so you could try to set `swipe: false,` where you define the slider image container `$('.slider-for').slick({`

If that doesn't work reiterate the process with any variable set in the `_.defaults` or `_.initials = {` that deals with mouse events.

Furthermore, if that doesn't work identify the part of the code that detect the mouse and change the cursor look. Comment it out. If it works notify the author of your findings.

*Hope it helps.*